# What are the security risks of replicating a server and giving root access to the copy of the server?

Tags: security

I have a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet. I made a "snapshot" of it and loaded it on to a separate droplet. I want to give someone root access to the new droplet without compromising the security of the original one.

The original droplet is a standard web server, running multiple WordPress installations.

I know that there's no problem with them seeing e.g. the public keys in SSH config files. I've also made sure there are no private keys in the `.ssh` folders of all users.

What security risks to the original server remain?

Comment: An answer would very much depend on how you define security .. the user might know e.g. the firewall setup, which services run on the server, and the user passwords e.g. via Rainbowtables....

Comment: And (I don't know Digital Oceans very well but) what means give someone root access? If it's a complete copy than how do you make sure the user doesn't use the same login on the original droplet?

Comment: @derHugo -- thanks. Re: root access, the original has only public key access, for the copy, I enabled root access by password and created a throwaway password.

Comment: What does this user actually need root rights for? Maybe it would be even saver creating an additional user who only is allowed to perform certain commands?